# Elastic Search search with source filtering ignores excludes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that looks pretty much like the below.  For some reason, ES 6.4 is ignoring the source filter and returning all the content.

Anybody have a clue?

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:49153/indexundertest/sometype/_search -d '{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "filter":[
            {
               "terms":{
                  "_id":[
                     "AA001"
                  ],
                  "boost":1.0
               }
            }
         ],
         "adjust_pure_negative":true,
         "boost":1.0
      }
   },
   "_source":{
      "includes":[

      ],
      "excludes":[
         "content.es",
         "content.pt",
         "content.zh",
         "content.vi",
         "other.content.es",
         "other.content.pt",
         "other.content.zh",
         "other.content.vi"
      ]
   }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a problem with the mappings.

If I create the index without the mappings, the query with source filtering works as expected.  If I included the mappings, I'd see a strange result in the source.
It includes the content of the source in the key of the source field of the hits, but has "JSON" as the value.

Working on fixing my mappings.